# How do you swap services with other images in an app run with docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-image

Let’s say I have a docker-compose.yml like this:

```
version: “3.8”

services:
  a:
    image: a
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: a/Dockerfile
  b:
    image: b
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: b/Dockerfile
```

When I run `docker-compose build`, images for a and b will be generated and when I run `docker-compose up`, containers for a and b will run as services for my application.

But what if I want to swap out a or b with another image of a or b? Can I do that while the app is running or do I have to reconfigure the docker-compose.yml and restart it?

Comment: And furthermore, can I run the app from the images without modifying the docker-compose.yml?

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be done with the help of rolling update.There are options called `update_config` and `rollback_config` it should help you to swap your services